# What is the difference between AfterContentChecked and AfterViewChecked in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I am trying to learn what is the exact difference between these two life cycle hooks? Can anyone please explain me how to use them with any simple example? I just want to when exactly I should implement these interfaces?

Thank you.

Cheers.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- **view** addresses the template of the component
- **content** addresses the transcluded children of the current component (that you can transclude using the `<ng-content></ng-content>` element).

For full details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#afterview